# How many times do you write the digit 4 when writing all the numbers from 10 to 100?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How many times do you write the digit 4 when writing all the numbers from 10 to 100?

Is there a way of doing this without having to write down all the numbers?

Comment: What are you talking about??

Comment: @lila: What it means is that you need to repeat any information in the title, so that people can understand the question without even looking at the title. The **body** of your post currently starts with "sorry I don't know $\dots$."

Comment: Also - tell us what you have a problem with, and what you've tried, so we can help you better.
And I believe the "trigonometry" tag is inappropriate here.

Comment: I've inserted the bare minimum required for the body. The reason your question was downvoted was because you kinda sounded rude much like the girls that say to me, "Ermahgerd, whut a nurd!".

Comment: The first post of this question, i.e. the unedited one, was among the funnier things I've read on M.SE today.

Comment: @newb: We're trying to hide our shames. Don't expose them.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569902/if-all-of-the-integers-from-1-to-99999-are-written-down-in-a-list-how-many

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ How many times are you writing a $4$ as the first digit? And how many times as the second digit?